# Show that law of large numbers hold

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Given,Xi's are iid random variables and

$$f(x)= \frac{1+δ}{x^{2+δ}}$$ $δ>0$ and $X>1$

To show that law of larger numbers hold, I used khinchin's theorem which states that if Xi's are iid then a necessary condition for law of large numbers to hold is that E(Xi) exists.
Well, I am unable to show the existence of mean. When I integrate and take limits the answer I am getting is infinity.

Comment: You must be doing the integral wrong.  Suggest you post your working so that someone can find the error.

Comment: Solving E(x):On integration, taking the constants, (1+δ)/-δ outside the term that remains is x^(-δ) within the limits 1 to infinity. Taking limits the answer is infinity.

Comment: By "law of large numbers" do you mean the weak LLN or strong LLN?

Comment: The question just mentions " law of large numbers ".

Comment: About my comment on integration: wouldn't taking limits x^(-δ) from 1 to infinity, give the final answer, E(X)= (1+δ)/δ? Does this imply that law of larger numbers is obeyed? Do I have to check if v(Xn)/n^2 is also finite?

Comment: Since the $X_n$ are iid, $\mathbb E[|X_1|]<\infty$ is sufficient for the strong law of large numbers to hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X_1] &= \int_\mathbb R xf_{X_1}(x)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_1^\infty \frac{1+\delta}{x^{1+\delta}}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac{1+\delta}\delta<\infty.
\end{align}
It follows from the strong law of large numbers that $S_n:=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ converges almost surely to $\mathbb E[X_1]=\frac{1+\delta}\delta$, i.e.
$$\mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = \frac{1+\delta}\delta\right)=1 $$
and from the weak law of large numbers that $S_n$ converges in probability to $\frac{1+\delta}\delta$, i.e.
$$\sup_{\varepsilon>0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left( \left|S_n - \frac{1+\delta}\delta\right|>\varepsilon\right)=0. $$

Comment: You're welcome!